# Mocking ObjectMapper Extension Functions with Mockk

Tags: kotlin, jackson, mocking

I have been trying to use [Mockk](https://github.com/mockk/mockk) to mock the following extension function for the Jackson `ObjectMapper`:

```
inline fun <reified T: Any> ObjectMapper.convertValue(from: Any): T = convertValue(from, jacksonTypeRef<T>())
```

The documentation indicates that I need to do something like this:

```
mockkStatic("com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.ExtensionsKt")
every {
   ObjectMapper().convertValue<SNSEvent>(any<Map<String, Any>>())
} returns event
```

However when I do this i get the following error:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method net/bytebuddy/renamed/java/util/Map$ByteBuddy$smykbfJj.isEmpty()Z is abstract

at net.bytebuddy.renamed.java.util.Map$ByteBuddy$smykbfJj.isEmpty(Unknown Source)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:516)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:30)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:292)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:3567)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:3530)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:3518)
at eventlogger.mapper.EventMapperImplTest$objectMapper$1$1.invoke(EventMapperImplTest.kt:85)
at eventlogger.mapper.EventMapperImplTest$objectMapper$1$1.invoke(EventMapperImplTest.kt:13)
at io.mockk.impl.eval.RecordedBlockEvaluator$record$block$1.invoke(RecordedBlockEvaluator.kt:22)
at io.mockk.impl.recording.JvmAutoHinter.autoHint(JvmAutoHinter.kt:23)
at io.mockk.impl.eval.RecordedBlockEvaluator.record(RecordedBlockEvaluator.kt:31)
at io.mockk.impl.eval.EveryBlockEvaluator.every(EveryBlockEvaluator.kt:25)
at io.mockk.MockKDsl.internalEvery(API.kt:93)
at io.mockk.MockKKt.every(MockK.kt:104)
at eventlogger.mapper.EventMapperImplTest.<init>(EventMapperImplTest.kt:66)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:352)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:60)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:208)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassTestDescriptor.java:195)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$0(ClassTestDescriptor.java:185)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$1(ClassTestDescriptor.java:189)
at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$2(ClassTestDescriptor.java:188)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:81)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:58)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.prepare(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:89)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:74)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:55)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Another attempt was to change it so that it accepts the actual map that will be passed:

```
 mockkStatic("com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.ExtensionsKt")
    every {
        ObjectMapper().convertValue<SNSEvent>(map)
    } returns event
```

This produces another error:

```
io.mockk.MockKException: Missing calls inside every { ... } block.

at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.StubbingState.checkMissingCalls(StubbingState.kt:14)
at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.StubbingState.recordingDone(StubbingState.kt:8)
at io.mockk.impl.recording.CommonCallRecorder.done(CommonCallRecorder.kt:42)
at io.mockk.impl.eval.RecordedBlockEvaluator.record(RecordedBlockEvaluator.kt:48)
at io.mockk.impl.eval.EveryBlockEvaluator.every(EveryBlockEvaluator.kt:25)
at io.mockk.MockKDsl.internalEvery(API.kt:93)
at io.mockk.MockKKt.every(MockK.kt:104)
at eventlogger.mapper.EventMapperImplTest.setUpWorks(EventMapperImplTest.kt:81)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:436)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:170)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:166)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:113)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:58)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:112)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:55)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Reading the documentation again it suggests that the class name can be unexpected:

> This is standard Kotlin behaviour that may be unpredictable for user of mocking library. Use Tools -> Kotlin -> Show Kotlin Bytecode or check .class files in JAR archive to detect such names.

As such I unzipped the jar and discovered the following class `com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.ExtensionsKt$convertValue$$inlined$jacksonTypeRef$1.class` and I attempted to use it instead:

```
   mockkStatic("com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.ExtensionsKt\$convertValue\$\$inlined\$jacksonTypeRef\$1")
    every {
        ObjectMapper().convertValue<SNSEvent>(map)
    } returns event
```

This produced the same error and logged another:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.ExtensionsKt and com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.ExtensionsKt$convertValue$$inlined$jacksonTypeRef$1 disagree on InnerClasses attribute
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaringClass0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaringClass(Class.java:1235)
at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$ForLoadedType.getDeclaringType(TypeDescription.java:7255)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.InstrumentedType$Factory$Default$1.represent(InstrumentedType.java:227)
at net.bytebuddy.ByteBuddy.redefine(ByteBuddy.java:698)
at net.bytebuddy.ByteBuddy.redefine(ByteBuddy.java:676)
at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.transformation.InliningClassTransformer.transform(InliningClassTransformer.kt:70)
at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:428)
at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses0(Native Method)
at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:144)
at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.transformation.InlineInstrumentation.execute(InlineInstrumentation.kt:39)
at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.StaticProxyMaker.staticProxy(StaticProxyMaker.kt:33)
at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.JvmStaticMockFactory.staticMockk(JvmStaticMockFactory.kt:31)
at eventlogger.mapper.EventMapperImplTest.<init>(EventMapperImplTest.kt:291)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:352)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:60)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:208)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassTestDescriptor.java:195)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$0(ClassTestDescriptor.java:185)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$1(ClassTestDescriptor.java:189)
at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$2(ClassTestDescriptor.java:188)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:81)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:58)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.prepare(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:89)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:74)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:55)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

I know that a possible solution would be to not use the extension function and to use the original Java `convertValue` function. However given the choice I would like to be able to use the extension functions in my code and mock them if possible.

Comment: Just for the future, I subscribed only for mockk tag, so accidentally found this one.

Comment: Looks like an issue with ByteBuddy transformation on the first sight. I don't think such traces are good for stackoverflow. Can you submit it here: https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues. A bit later I will try to rerpoduce it.